# redux- state changes but component doesn't display re-rendered view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, display

inProgress is false by default so display is equal to value from else statement. After state changes I see in console log from if statement("DISPLAY = CONFIRM") so display =  but view doesn't changes. What is wrong?

```
class Registration extends Component {

render(){
    let display;
    if(this.props.inProgress){
        console.log("DISPLAY = CONFIRM");
        display = <RegistrationConfirmFormContainer />;
    }else {
        console.log("DISPLAY = REGISTER FORM");
        display = <RegistrationFormContainer />;
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {display}
        </div>
    )
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
return{
    inProgress: state.ReducerRegistrationPanel.inProgress
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Registration)
```

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: No, I don't have any errors. I just have consol logs which I expect

Comment: you have to set up a constructor, pass props as param, then inside it call super and pass it props as well.

Comment: The code seems ok. I guess  <RegistrationConfirmFormContainer /> = <RegistrationFormContainer /> cause the problem . Could you replace the both to <span>change</span> and <span>not change</span> and observe it.

Comment: I checked both components separately and they are shown correctly

Comment: The easiest way to achieve the view re-rendering is to modify the state. So you can create an initial state(for this particular component only) and then change it with setState depending on props you pass in

Comment: I see you didnt initialize your variable `display`. go ahead and set it to `null`

Comment: Problem solved: code beyond is correct. I found problem in different place totally unattached with this code - import was incorrect

Comment: you said both components work fine seperately!! I wonder how could this be an `import` issue!

Comment: anyway, glad it's solved now.

Comment: because it was other import, not connected with those components but it destroyed the working of app

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do this with trinary statement:

```
render(){
    return this.props.inProgress ? <RegistrationConfirmFormContainer /> : <RegistrationFormContainer /> 
}
```

This way you don't need to wrap it with a div, plus it looks better.